# What is the correct way to emit a value after another stream has completed?

Tags: rxjs, ionic3

i am trying to 'think in streams'. What is the correct way to emit a value to stream B after stream A has completed?

my current implementation is as follows:

```
streamADelete$(data)
 .do(() => dismiss())
 .subscribe(() => streamB$.next()) // this seems wrong!
```

to me there is something wrong with this implementation

Comment: The (first) subscribe callback is called every time an event is emitted. Not when the stream completes. The third callback passed to subscribe is called when the stream completes.

Comment: i understand that with code above subscribe will trigger an observer next which in turn will call next opon a subject of stream B, but is there an operator to emit a value to stream B without subscribing to the first one?

Comment: @EmilIakoupov, we might be more helpful if you could explain what are your bigger goals with this code. What is streamA, why do you need to emit to streamB?

Comment: If you want to react only after stream A completes you should use `subscribe({ complete: () => streamB$.next() })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main goal is to call streamB.next(), but somewhere before the subscribe block, then the correct place to do that would be the tap() operator, which is meant for doing side-effects.

```
streamADelete$(data)
    .pipe(
        tap(() => streamB$.next()),
        // Continue with your next operator
    )
```

This does seem like a strange thing to do though, we are usually able to achieve most things without doing side-effects. I am not exactly sure what your use-case is, but another pattern that might be helpful could be to split your stream into two like this:

```
streamADelete$.pipe(
    // Do whatever you want to do in your original stream here
)
.subscribe();

streamADelete$.pipe(
    // Do whatever you wanted to do in you streamB$ stream here
)
.subscribe();
```

(Your RxJS also seems a little strange, are you using an old version of RxJS / following some old tutorials?)

Comment: Thank you
i am using an older versioin of RxJS (not using pipe currently) - i had some issues when tried to upgrade...
esentially tap is the same as do, but i would still need to subscribe in order to execut e the observer. The thing is i have an angular async operator in the template which is bound to an observable that is composed of many streams (merge operator), so there is a subscribtion on that end, that is why i was looking for a way to avoid another subsscribtion and just realized that i can create another subject to execute streamA$ and then map it to streamB$...